# Как превратить объект объектов в массив и вывести комментарии пациента в React

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных, reactjs

Здраствуйте, я новичок в JS и React, я хочу выводить все комментарии текущего пациента, как я понял мне нужно превратить объект объектов в массив и пройтись по нему методом map

Вот что я получаю `{console.log(selectedPatient.patientComments)}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
const PatientInfo = () => {
const { selectedPatient } = useContext(PatientContext);
const moment = require('moment');

const commentInput = React.createRef();
const patientService = new PatientService();

const addPatientComment = () => {
    const date = moment();
    const newCommentForDatabase = { comment: commentInput.current.value, patient_id: selectedPatient.id, date: date };
    patientService.saveComment(newCommentForDatabase, selectedPatient.id);
}

const getArrayOfComments = () => {

}

return (
    <div className='content'>

        <PatientHeader />

        <div className='info'>
            <div className='short-info'>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date of Birth:</td>
                        <td>{selectedPatient.birth}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gender:</td>
                        <td>{selectedPatient.gender}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Country:</td>
                        <td>{selectedPatient.country}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>State:</td>
                        <td>{selectedPatient.state}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address:</td>
                        <td>{selectedPatient.city}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div className='comments'>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <h3 className='comments-text'>Comments:</h3>
                    </p>
                    <ul>
                        {console.log(selectedPatient.patientComments)}

                        // **не работает Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**
                        {selectedPatient.patientComments.map((c) =>
                            <li>
                                <div className='new-comment'>
                                    <div>
                                        <b>{moment(c.date).format('ll')}</b>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        {c.comment}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div className='create-commentInput'>
                    <input  ref={commentInput} className='form-control' type="text"/>
                    <button onClick={addPatientComment} className='add-btn'>+</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Метод savePatient

```
saveComment(commentForDatabase, patientID) {
    axios.post(`${url}/patientLoad/${patientID}/patientComments.json`, commentForDatabase)
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
        .then(() => {
            // always executed
        });
}
```

Добавилась новая ошибка

```
                     <ul>
                        {
                            Object.keys(selectedPatient.patientComments).map(comment => {
                                comment = selectedPatient.patientComments[comment];
                                return(
                                    <li>
                                        <div className='new-comment'>
                                            <div>
                                                <b>{moment(comment.date).format('ll')}</b>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                {comment.comment}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужна дополнительная информация пишите, буду благодарен любой помощи

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(selectedPatient.patientComments).map(comment => {
    comment = selectedPatient.patientComments[comment];
    <li>
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, можете посмотреть что я сделал не так? Добавил ошибку выше

Comment: а если так `Object.keys(selectedPatient?.patientComments || {})`